# Application Insights with big data

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am looking to use a jvm-profiler (https://github.com/uber-common/jvm-profiler) on my spark clusters and correlate this with my application logs. On a large cluster (about 1000 executors), this will produce a lot of data. I tried dumping it into an influxDb which worked well. However, then I have to manage the influxDb. My stack is all in Azure, and we use Application Insights.

Could application insights handle this kind of load, or is there a better Azure alternative. My plan would then be to use Power BI to create dashboards around this data.

A current alternative is to use influxDb with Chronograf to visualize the data.

Comment: For Time Series storage there is also [Azure Time Series Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/time-series-insights/)

Answer (score 0):

[App Insights will ingest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/service-limits#application-insights) a maximum of 32,ooo events a second. The default data cap is 100GB per day, but you can increase this to 1,000 GB on your own or request a higher cap from support.

[Making use of sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing) will reduce the total volume and your bill- you can control how this is done so you only sample data where you want to. Generally, cumulative metrics are sent separately so things like request counts aren't affected by sampling.